# css working fine with chrome, but changes with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am usign the following style to display words in webpage.

```
<h2><font color="#5D5D5D" size="2" face=caecilia-light, face="helvetica,arial,sans-serif" >Hello world
```

my css is the following:

```
h2{
    color: #747474;
    font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-justify: auto;
    text-outline: none;
    text-overflow: clip;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    text-wrap: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

it works fine with chrome but the font changes when I open it in IE. How can I modify my code so that it will work in IE as it is working in chrome?

Comment: Did you notice that you've declared `font-family` and `font-size` twice?  Also, the `<font>` tag has been deprecated for a very long time but there's no point in using `font` tag when you're using CSS anyway.  You also declared the `face` attribute twice within the `font` tag along with some bad syntax... a comma and mismatched quotes?  Just slow down and proof-read your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a duplicate `font-family` and `font-size` property declared in `h2` - do away with one of them that you do not need.

Also, in your html `face="caecilia-light'` should be changed to `face="caecilia-light"` - In chrome, it is handled properly, but in IE it is an error, so it would pick up the second `face` attribute

Comment: i remove it but still nothing